# How to support actionable notifications only in watch app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode7, watchos-2

I am not implementing actionable notifications in my iPhone app but I want to implement Actionable notifications for companion Watch app..From Apple Documents I found out that We need to register for actionable notifications in Parent iPhone App..Is it possible to support actionable notifications in watch app by registering in Watch Kit extension class or is there any other possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Notification Essentials for watch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

> Apple Watch displays local and remote notifications only if the
>   containing iOS supports them. For information about how to support
>   local and remote notifications in your iOS app, see Local and Remote
>   Notification Programming Guide.

So there is not way you can support notification only for watch and not for parent app.

Comment: Apple Watch displays local and remote notifications only if the containing iOS supports them. Its for both local/ remote.You define notification action  in your user notification setting and those settings apply to either local notifications or remote notification. If your iOS support any kind of notification then you can define notification actions for that.